# Print only the current last line of streaming sed?

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I'm trying to store the current song title I get out of a webstream. Till now, I got it to only print songs titles, but it prints every single one...

```
mpg123 --timeout 10 http://mp3.example.com 2>&1 | sed -rn "s/.+StreamTitle='(.+)'\;.\1/p"
```

Now I want only the current last line of the output to be stored in a file. Is this possible while not starting new threads?

Comment: You could just pipe what you have to `tail -n1` but `sed` probably has a better method built in

Answer (score 3):

The last line can be referenced by the address `$` in front of the command `s`:

```
mpg123 --timeout 10 http://mp3.example.com 2>&1 | sed -rn "$s/.+StreamTitle='(.+)'\;.\1/p"
```

Comment: on streaming input, there is no end so sed (nor other tools) cannot take "last" line until the stream is not finish. The thiton's code is good on a closed stream.